# Computing determinant of X-matrix using permutations and blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, determinant, block-matrices

> Calculate the following determinant $$\det\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & 0 & ... &0&b_1 \\ 0&a_2 & ... &b_2&0 \\ &&... \\ 0 & b_{2n-1} & ... &a_{2n-1}&0\\ b_{2n} & 0 & ... &0&a_{2n}\end{bmatrix}$$

---

We thought about using the idea of a determinant of blocks. Using that way we got  $a_1a_2..a_2n - b_1b_2...b_{2n}$ . Another thought was using the definition using permutations, but we are having trouble understanding why the rest of the permutations (except the identity permutation and the permutation that returns the last to the first etc) eventually become 0. We would like to verify correctness/get an explanation on how to solve this one using permutations and blocks.

Comment: We thought it was true, why isn't it here (or at all)?

Comment: $\mathrm{det}(\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}) = \mathrm{det}(A)\mathrm{det}(D) - \mathrm{det}(B)\mathrm{det}(C)$ is not usually true, if the matrices $A,B,C,D$ don't commute with each other

Comment: Try Laplace's formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)

Comment: We're trying to prove what you said, assuming they do commute. We don't know if we're allowed to multiply by a matrix X in a determinant of blocks, and then multiply by 1/detX (the same way you'd do with a scalar)

Comment: ? (would really love an answer - the test is tommorow :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laplace expansion should give you the simplest way to solve the problem, but if you insist on using permutations and block matrices, you may first move the last column forward to the second column, and then move the last row upward to the second row. So, the required determinant is equal to the determinant of
$$
\pmatrix{a_1&b_1\\ b_{2n}&a_{2n}\\ &&a_2&\cdots&b_2\\ &&&\cdots\\ &&b_{2n-1}&\cdots&a_{2n-1}}
$$
and you may proceed recursively.

Comment: That's a very nice way! We really lost our way using the Laplace way... We'd love to see that solution too... And another question: So the final solution is the same as ours eventually?

Comment: @user1685224 **No.** The determinant of a block diagonal matrix is the product of the determinants of its diagonal blocks. So, the answer should be $$(a_1a_{2n}-b_1b_{2n})(a_2a_{2n-1}-b_2b_{2n-1})\cdots(a_na_{n+1}-b_nb_{n+1}).$$