# Determinant of the sum of tridiagonal and anti-tridiagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

$A$ is a tridiagonal matrix and $B$ is an anti-tridiagonal matrix, both of size $n\times n$, such that $B^2$ is a diagonal matrix. Is it possible to express $\det(A+B)$ in terms of $\det(A),\det(B),n$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

In fact, any clue to get the spectrum of $A+B$ will also help. I know that the Courant-Weyl inequalities give bounds of the eigenvalues of $A+B$, but obtaining only the bounds are not sufficient for my problem.

Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to permute rows and columns?

Comment: @RodrigoAzevedo I don't think permutations will help. However, the eigenvalues of $A,B,B^2$ are all known. Is there any way to get the eigenvalues of $A+B$?

Comment: I was thinking of something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3784885/339790).